# CSS not working on different machine

Tags: html, css

Sometimes back, I have developed a small web application to learn CSS and Ajax. When I deployed it on google app engine, on my machine it is looking as intended. But, when I access it on other computers, the alignment, button styling, table positioning everything looking weird. On IE the problem is severe and nothing is working properly.
Now what I have done till now:

1. I have included Mayers reset.css thinking that this may help me. But I don't know how to use it effectively ? I have my style.css file which I am including in each web page after reset.css. I haven't changed anything in reset.css
2. Earlier I was using 'px' for div and element positioning. Now, changed everything to use percentage sign but still no luck.

Let me know if you people need my code. Its huge thats why not giving here.`This is the [application link](http://myentrancetest.appspot.com/) you can check, but I bet it is looking far more better in my laptop.

Comment: Why are the links to the CSS resets commented out?

Comment: Whats not working with the css?  The inline stuff seems to be rendering and the external sheets are commented out

Comment: Are you checking it in the same browser (version) on these other machines? Different browsers and browser versions of those browsers will display the content differently, wild concept!

Comment: sometimes the stylesheet is cached in the browser of the other machine. right click the background of the page and reload/refresh. i have to remind my clients of that all the time.

Comment: It's not about reset.css or px. The layout is really messy...

Comment: @Dani:yes, indeed its looking messy. Refactoring it again.Will update once done. Actually first page refactoring is done. Hopefully it is not that much messy now. Will ask my friend to check on his computer once he is online.@j08691:yes, sorry i forgot to uncomment it on production.

Comment: @Shmiddty: Even on the same browser on other computers, it was creating problem. Now as per the suggestion of Dani have included doc_type and re-factored first page. Will ask someone to check and update you people.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I recommend you to declare the HTML DOCTYPE:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration

It determines the layout mode that browser uses to render the page ...

Comment: @Sorry for delay response..It was useful..Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to follow some standards when you develop a web page:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmyentrancetest.appspot.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Now I got habbit to use validator for my each page.Thanks for pointing to the url.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick source view, I found this;

```
#login_hr{
  position: absolute;
  width: 400%;
  color: #4F32F0;
}
```

Why 400%? I think it is stretching your page outside. Change it to something like 100%. Give it a try.